# Bulk async calls to FB and G+ count endpoints fail

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, asynchronous, sails.js

my app has a controller that outputs the total social count for various pages: http://pastebin.com/MLBTb3mi

..it works fine when i'm making a few calls at a time but say when there is a website of 1000 urls and i want to update the social count for each of the urls, it breaks when its hit with volume calls asynchronously - particularly g+ and fb break. Here's the console error I get as the response to the call made to fb's graph id (this is the 'body' response - please refer to line 74 of the controller: http://pastebin.com/MLBTb3mi

```
facebook body is {"id":"970371719648388","created_time":"2015-04-02T07:43:09+0000","is_scrap
ed":false,"type":"website","updated_time":"2015-04-02T07:43:09+0000","url":"http:\/\/www.zappos.com\/womens-clothing\/"}
facebook result is undefined
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue and to make the controller work smoothly?

I tried making bulk calls using sharedcount.com and i'm able to do 10s of thousand of simultaneous calls without any problem. How can I write my controller to handle such bulk operations without using external services like sharedcount?

Answer (score 1):

You should examine the status code of the response.  My guess is that you're getting rate-limited.  See the [Facebook page on rate-limiting](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/api-rate-limiting) for details; it doesn't discuss specific numbers on what will get you blocked, but it provides details on what to look for to indicate that you're being throttled.  The solution is to throttle requests on your end so that they don't go out too fast; you can use something as simple as [Lodash's `_.throttle`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/api-rate-limiting) for this.